# How to handle ICU formatted strings - Swift

Tags: swift, localization, translation, icu

I'm receiving an array of string formatted in ICU standard. Those strings will then be used for dynamic translations in app.

The strings have a format similar to this one:

```
"{n, plural, one {# month} other {# months}} after activation"
```

The question is, how can I automatically handle the plural forms?
Are there any libraries or any string transform in Swift that I can use in order to replace what's inside the curly braces with a value, similarly to what we do with %s or %d ?

Comment: Where are you receiving these strings from? Are they being received dynamically (e.g. from a web service), or statically (e.g. loaded from a file)? [e.g., do you have the option to pre-process these in any way] And when you say "ICU standard", are you referring to an ICU API used to generate/process these, or are you referring to Unicode itself?

Comment: @ItaiFerber it is coming from a web service, so we do have an API with all of those strings. So there is no way for pre-process them if not when I receive them in the app. 
The idea is to match the string key with the new string that might contains plurals forms as in the example above. 
ICU is the standard for message formatting: https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/the-missing-guide-to-the-icu-message-format-d7f8efc50bab
You can find some more info there.
I actually have no clue on how I can handle this case

Comment: Got it. Is there a reason you can't use the ICU library itself, then? You should be able to use the official [ICU4C](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/) library and write Swift wrappers around the [`umsg`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/umsg_8h.html) APIs to make it a little bit easier to consume in Swift. (Your wrapper layer will need to convert Swift strings to and from UTF-16 to pass to ICU, but that should also be straightforward.)

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm just trying to see if there is a faster way than me rewriting pieces of code from another language into Swift. As it's very much time consuming

Comment: Understood. There aren't any system APIs that handle this message format directly, and I'm not aware of any 3rd-party Swift libraries that were written specifically for this — hope you find something that works for your use-case, though!